# Detecting Close Scene or Change Scene

Tags: python, maya

HI I'm working with `Pyqt4` to make a UI in `Maya`, but I want that the UI close or refresh when the user open or change Scene.

Is there a way in python to detect this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scriptJob`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/scriptJob.html) is what you need.

The following might with some customization might be helpful.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def refresher():
    # the function which does the closing/refreshing
    pass

cmds.scriptJob(e=["NewSceneOpened", refresher])
cmds.scriptJob(e=["SceneOpened", refresher])
cmds.scriptJob(e=["flushingScene", refresher])
```